# LMGTFY (Oh, yes, please, would you?)

Tags: discussion

So, I've been [LMGTFY](http://lmgtfy.com/)¹ed. I know this practice is discouraged on SO and SE, but is it also discouraged here at SFF.se? Different sites have different norms, so I'm asking specifically about SFF (i.e. I don't necessarily need to be redirected to SO or SE).

**Is LMGTFY discouraged here? How do I best deal with a LMGTFY comment (Flag it as non-constructive? Ignore it? Comment back?)?** I was thinking flagging a LMGTFY comment as non-constructive would be the best option, but, then again, I don't want to assume when it comes to flagging and possibly clogging up the mods' inboxes.

**ETA:** **SQB** suggested I provide context. A question was asked that introduced a non-canonical theory into a canonical situation, without any links or references for us to refer to in order to better understand the OP's theory. In my answer to the OP, I mentioned that it would be nice if he/she provided said links or references, mainly out of courtesy. *Another user* then left a LMGTFY comment -- I want to be clear that it was *not* the OP who was rude, but rather it was another user. The OP did edit in links to references on his/her theory, which was thoughtful and helpful.

¹<sub>You thought I was going to provide a written explanation of LMGTFY here, didn't you? (I'm sorry, I'm sorry -- I couldn't resist! Just a bit of cheek in light of the topic ... I am asking the question in all seriousness.)</sub>

Comment: [Well...](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=LMGTFY+(Oh%2C+yes%2C+please%2C+would+you%3F))

Comment: ^ I laughed

Anyway, but imagine that the question is stupidly trivial (for example, "Who is Voldemort"? Whoever asks that clearly has made no research effort, and as such http://bit.ly/1kx3K7h would be enough

Comment: @Oak It would be enough, but it wouldn't be appropriate. The whole point of LMGTFY is to be passive aggressive, that's not the kind of content we want on our site (or any other site in the StackExchange network). Downvote with extreme prejudice, leave a direct link to Wikipedia or another reputable source if you really wish, and move on.

Comment: From that perspective, then you are correct lmgtfy would actually be a very rude awnser. In that case, i'd consider the replyer to be contributing to a non-constructive awnser

Comment: What if I said I didn't know what LMGTFY is? Would someone google it for me please? :D

Comment: @ClickRick - http://tinyurl.com/5kk4ou

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can safely flag LMGTFY and similar comments as not constructive.

Some sites, like SO, have lmgtfy on a blacklist so comments with such a link can't even be posted, but we don't need such a block until and unless it becomes a frequent problem.

Answer (score 2):

If it really was easy to find on Google, it's a missed opportunity for an answer. So I wouldn't mind you (the OP), or anybody else snatching that comment and turning it into an actual answer, for fun and <del>profit</del> rep!

If the LMGTFY doesn't answer your question, it may have looked too simple, so you can take that as a hint to edit for clarity.